# Two equal combine keys do not get to the same reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, combiners

I'm making a Hadoop application in Java with the MapReduce framework.

I use only Text keys and values for both input and output. I use a combiner to do an extra step of computations before reducing to the final output.

But I have the problem that the keys do not go to the same reducer.
I create and add the key/value pair like this in the combiner:

```
public static class Step4Combiner extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {
    private static Text key0 = new Text();
    private static Text key1 = new Text();

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                key0.set("KeyOne");
                key1.set("KeyTwo");
                context.write(key0, new Text("some value"));
                context.write(key1, new Text("some other value"));
        }

}   

public static class Step4Reducer extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {

            public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                System.out.print("Key:" + key.toString() + " Value: ");
                String theOutput = "";
                for (Text val : values) {
                    System.out.print("," + val);
                }
                System.out.print("\n");

                context.write(key, new Text(theOutput));
            }

}
```

In the main i creates the job like this:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();

Job job4 = new Job(conf, "Step 4");
job4.setJarByClass(Step4.class);

job4.setMapperClass(Step4.Step4Mapper.class);
job4.setCombinerClass(Step4.Step4Combiner.class);
job4.setReducerClass(Step4.Step4Reducer.class);

job4.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job4.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job4.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job4, new Path(outputPath));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job4, new Path(finalOutputPath));            

System.exit(job4.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

The output in stdout printed from the reducer is this:

```
Key:KeyOne Value: ,some value
Key:KeyTwo Value: ,some other value
Key:KeyOne Value: ,some value
Key:KeyTwo Value: ,some other value
Key:KeyOne Value: ,some value
Key:KeyTwo Value: ,some other value
```

Which makes no sense since the keys are the same, and therefore it should be 2 reducers with 3 of the same values in it's Iterable

Hope you can help me get to the bottom of this :)

Comment: It would help if you get us the complete code ;) As seeing the code snippets here, it looks fine. Problem is somewhere else I believe.

Comment: Are you using the same class as your combiner as well as reducer ?

Comment: I added the whole combiner and reducer, that are all dummy just to show the problem at its minimum.

Comment: If you add only one set of values in your combiner and your are ignoring the values coming in from mapper then how come there are 3 set of outputs?

Comment: In the mapper three different keys are added, so the combiner is called three times.

Comment: If is only add one key/value pair in each combiner, or i use the same key for both, it all works just fine.

Comment: I believe this is the way then hadoop behaves! ie when you do not emit keys as per the passed key from the combiner it doesn't merge them into the same input group! It is indeed weird. I am able to reproduce it locally.

Comment: I posted an answer but now I am thinking it won't help. Can you also post the code for the part where you are setting the combiner/reducer etc.?

Comment: I have added the code from my main method to the original question.

Comment: I notice you are running some `job3` instead of `job4` in the end. Is that a typo?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the combiner and put the same code in the mapper?

Comment: If I replace the mapper with the code from the combiner and remove the combiner, it works just fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most probably because your combiner is running in both map and reduce phases (a little known 'feature').

Basically you are amending the key in the combiner, which may or may not run as map outputs are merged together in the reducer. After the combiner is run (reduce side), the keys are fed through the grouping comparator to determine what values back the Iterable passed to the reduce method (i'm skirting around the streaming aspect of the reduce phase here - the iterable is not backed by a set or list of values, more calls to iterator().next() return true if the grouping comparator detemines the current key and the last key are the same)

You can try and detect the current combiner phase side (map or reduce) by inspecting the Context (there is a `Context.getTaskAttempt().isMap()` method, but i have some memory of this being problematic too, and there even might be a JIRA ticket about this somewhere).

Bottom line, don't amend the key in the combiner unless you can find away to bypass this bevaviour *if* the combiner is running reduce side.

**EDIT**
So investigating @Amar's comment, i put together some code ([pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/PH5TsN6x)) which adds in some verbose comparators, combiners, reducers etc. If you run a single map job then in the reduce phase no combiner will run, and map output will not be sorted again as it is already assumed to be sorted.

It is assumed to be sorted as it is sorted prior to being sent into the combiner class, and it assumed that the keys will come out untouched - hence still sorted. Remember a Combiner is meant to Combine values for a given key.

So with a single map and the given combiner, the reducer sees the keys in KeyOne, KeyTwo, KeyOne, KeyTwo, KeyOne order. The grouping comparator sees a transition between them and hence you get 6 calls to the reduce function

If you use two mappers, then the reducer knows it has two sorted segments (one from each map), and so still needs to sort them prior to reducing - but because the number of segments is below a threshold, the sort is done as an inline stream sort (again the segments are assumed to be sorted). You still be the wrong output with two mappers (10 records output from the reduce phase).

So again, don't amend the key in the combiner, this is not what the combiner is intended for.

Comment: I have run it in debug mode and when I had 2 unique keys emitted from my mapper, the combiner's reduce method was called twice and in reducer each key was repeated twice (with `values'` size being just 1 instead of 2). Combiner's reduce isn't getting called in reduce phase as you are saying!

Comment: can you pastebin the entire code you are running @Amar, and the test input you are running

Comment: yeah +1, so basically one shouldn't change the key in combiner!

Comment: Yeah +1 from me as well, thanks for helping me at least understand the problem!
I chose to make another Map/reduce in my "Job-chain".. I don't know if it is the best solution, but it works..

Comment: There are two issues here one addressed pretty well.  The partitioner however runs immediately after the map before sort or combine.  The partition in some measure determines how the records will arrive at the reducer as the records are only sorted within the partition, the assumption that all values with the same key will be in the same partition.  This assumption becomes false if you modify keys within the combiner and now the same key may be in multiple partitions.  They will be grouped within the partitions but not globally.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the combiner instead:

```
context.write(new Text("KeyOne"), new Text("some value"));
context.write(new Text("KeyTwo"), new Text("some other value"));
```

The only way I see such a thing happening is if the `key0` from one combiner is not found to be equal to the `key0` from another. I am not sure how it would behave in case of keys pointing to the exact same instance (which is what would happen if you make the keys static).

Comment: That was actually my first approach, and gave the same result :(